# Запятая перед "то"

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, спп, местоимения

Нужна ли запятая перед "то"?

"А их лагерь я не видела, поэтому даже если по деревьям подкрадусь, всё равно не пойму, то ли место".

Answer (score 3):

Запятая перед ***то*** нужна. Также необходима ещё одна, перед ***даже если***.

*А их лагерь я не видела, поэтому, **даже если по деревьям подкрадусь**, всё равно не пойму, **то ли место.***

Придаточное предложение условия (*даже если по деревьям подкрадусь*) можно убрать совсем без потери смысла или переставить в другое место.

***То ли место*** является самостоятельным (неполным) предложением со своей грамматической основой: *[это] то место или не то?* А значит, должно отделяться от предшествующего предложения.

Comment: А в таком предложении: "А их лагерь я не видела, поэтому, если по деревьям подкрадусь, всё равно не пойму...". Не могу вспомнить, как у нас там строго по правилам – нужна запятая перед ЕСЛИ или нет? Розенталь приводит примеры для сочетаний "наречие + союз", у него тоже подстановкой решается такая задача? Какая-то проблемная тема с этим наречием… Просветите, пжста (исключительно в свободное время и если будет желание). :)  Вопрос от  неблагодарного участника, получившего плюсик

Comment: Почему неблагодарного?  А я получил здесь плюсик и решил вам поставить (спортивное поведение). Посмотрел мельком – у вас на эту тему, в том числе с "поэтому когда", очень много вопросов-ответов, что и добавить уже, наверно, будет нечего. Надо внимательно прочитать.

Comment: Не надо читать, не тратьте время. Извините, еще вопрос. А по слуху вы в упрощенном предложении поставили бы запятую?

Comment: Когда я отвечал на этот вопрос, я еще не слишком был погружен в правила. С этим "поэтому" черт ногу сломит, каша в голове. Поэтому сейчас я думаю так. Ни в упрощенном предложении, ни тем более с добавлением частицы наш интонац. анализ не поможет (хотя всё же эти три слова лучше читаются с ударением на "поэтому" и паузой перед "даже"). Здесь я ориетируюсь на синтаксис. Если есть вторая часть союза (если... то), запятую не ставим. Если нет и можно переставить придаточное – ставим. Еще вспомнился вопрос о запятой после частицы "неужели". Там такая же ситуация, грамматическая и семантическая.

Comment: Если запятую не ставить, тогда при удалении всего, что находится между двумя запятыми, смысл теряется. Потому что "поэтому" относится к "всё равно не пойму".

Comment: Вот странно... Всё не отпускает мысль о том, что перестановки и удаления далеко не всегда не нарушают синтаксис. Например, в случае встречи одиночного и двойного союзов изъятие приводит к несуразице.

Comment: Спасибо, все-таки я озадачила вас проблемами. Я отвечу вам отдельно, здесь места нет, да и вопрос общего характера.

Comment: ""То ли место" является неполным предложением." - не согласен. Предложение - полное. Место - подлежащее, То - сказуемое.

Comment: @user190920  Я сначала так и написал (можно посмотреть правку). Но поразмыслив, решил по-другому. В любом случае на решение вопроса это не влияет.

Answer (score 1):

*А их лагерь я не видела, **поэтому даже если** по деревьям подкрадусь, всё равно не пойму, **то ли (это) место**.*

1) Запятая перед ***то*** нужна, Александр все верно объяснил.

2) Запятую перед ***даже если*** ставят не всегда: паузы там нет, а наречие с частицей можно отнести к союзу ЕСЛИ.

3) Последнее предложение понимается с трудом, хорошо бы добавить частицу ***это***.

Пример без запятой перед ***даже если***:

*Далеко не стандартно заполнение этого понятия и у самого Иванова, **поэтому даже если** в своих наиболее привычных толкованиях «событие» и отторгается от ивановского понимания* ... [Л. А. Гоготишвили. Символизм Вяч. Иванова на фоне имяславия (2006)]

Answer (score 1):

**Комментарий** к ответу (и к другим комментариям)

Спасибо, Александр, за ваше  внимание к вопросу. Я уже говорила, что не читаю своих старых ответов – мы таким образом **обращаемся к себе в прошлом,** не движемся вперед, это тормозит наше развитие. Поэтому я забываю всё, что было написано раньше, и даже  правила откладываю в сторону. Я решаю задачу заново, с самого начала.

Основная задача художественной литературы  – это **передать смысл сказанного** в определенной ситуации, поэтому надо книгу открыть, то есть обратиться **к контексту.** Это предложение звучит по-разному, и всё можно объяснить **грамматикой**. Мы имеем возможность  подчеркнуть или не подчеркивать наречие ***поэтому***. При его подчеркивании (обособлении)  **главное предложение** будет интонационно выделено,  придаточное уходит на второй план. При отсутствии подчеркивания мы как бы имеем **единое СПП** с определенной семантикой (обо всем этом говорится в грамматике Кустовой).

А теперь присмотримся к тексту. Прорисовывается два сообщения: (1) я лагерь не видела, поэтому все равно не пойму; (2) я лагерь не видела, поэтому даже при этих условиях не пойму. Что лучше и вернее, это уже можно определить по контексту. Когда читаешь полный текст, чувствуется, что надо выбрать, даже по таким **незначительным** семантическим оттенкам.

**И о перестановке.** Это формальный прием, он позволяет  однозначно решить задачу д**ля двойного союза,** там уж точно запятая не ставится. Но если второй части нет, то мы вовсе не обязаны обособлять придаточное **по формальному правилу** – здесь уже авторский выбор. Вот поэтому меня так не радуют **манипуляции с перестановкой**. Это слишком формальный и **упрощенный** подход, и в некоторых случаях правила не помогают выбрать верное решение, а **ограничивают** наши возможности.

И вот что нужно осознать на каком-то этапе собственного развития:  другой подход – это не отрицание правила, а более **глубокое его понимание**и расширение его возможностей.